# Casting Date Format in MySQL Statment

Tags: mysql, date, format

In case the Field Datatype in MySQL is DateTime and the value is Stored as

2017-03-22 09:00:00

Is there a need to Format the date Format for Logic Check with Function CURDATE()

For Example

```
  SELECT....
    FROM ....
  WHERE DateTime_Field = CURDATE()
```

In the WHERE Clause, do we need to format the date to get a correct result?

Comment: DateFormat column has no format

Comment: SELECT
`cio_master`.`Client_Check_Out`,
`cio_master`.`Client_Check_In`,
FROM `cio_master`
WHERE (`cio_master`.`Client_Check_Out` IS NULL AND `cio_master`.`Client_Check_In` IS NULL)  is returning Nil Records

Comment: Is there any way to extract only Date from the DateTime Field and compare it with CURDATE()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations where your `DateTime_Field` also contains an actual time of day you need to cut that part away by applying the `date()` function:

```
SELECT....
    FROM ....
  WHERE DATE(DateTime_Field) = CURDATE()
```